# robot_localization use case with landmarks

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a non holonomic mobile base that I want to localize. When I start it I get its odometry published to /odom but with covariances of 0 for both twist and pose. I also fixed a camera on it and can observe and identify landmarks at known global positions and then can estimate the pose of the robot in the world. If I understood well, I set the world frame in my launch file to the map frame  as explaned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization)

> If you are fusing global absolute
> position data that is subject to
> discrete jumps (e.g., GPS or position
> updates from landmark observations)
> then:
>
> ```
> a- Set your world_frame to your map_frame value
>
> b- MAKE SURE something else is generating the odom->base_link transform. Note that this can even be another instance of a robot_localization state estimation node. However, that instance should not fuse the global data.
> ```

Here Is my current launch file:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="use_sim" default="true"/>
    <param name="/use_sim_time" type="bool" value="$(arg use_sim)" />

    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">

      <param name="frequency" value="30"/>
      <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1"/>
      <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>

      <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
      <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
      <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
      <param name="world_frame" value="map"/>

      <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>
      <param name="odom0" value="/odom"/>
      <param name="pose0" value="/my_pose"/>
     
      <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                      false, false, false,
                                      true,  true, false,
                                      false, false, true,
                                      false, false, false]</rosparam>

      <rosparam param="pose0_config">[true,  true,  false,
                                      false, false, true,
                                      false, false, false,
                                      false, false, false,
                                      false, false, false]</rosparam>

      <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
      <param name="pose0_differential" value="false"/>

      <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
      <param name="pose0_relative" value="false"/>

      <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>

      <param name="odom0_pose_rejection_threshold" value="5"/>
      <param name="odom0_twist_rejection_threshold" value="1"/>
      <param name="pose0_rejection_threshold" value="2"/>

      <param name="debug"           value="false"/>
      <param name="debug_out_file"  value="debug_ekf_localization.txt"/>

    </node>

</launch>
```

I play a bag providing /odom and the odom->base_link transform and then launch robot_localization. The topic odometry_filtered is there but nothing gets published on it. At this stage there is nothing published to /my_pose as no landmarks are observed.

What is missing?

My odom message looks like this:

```
header: 
  seq: 4701
  stamp: 
    secs: 1439389120
    nsecs: 950957354
  frame_id: /odom
child_frame_id: /base_footprint
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 17.6170005798
      y: 0.433000028133
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.00999983404194
      w: 0.99995000041
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -0.286000013351
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

And here is the tf tree coming from the bag, the transform between map and odom was being published by amcl:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216116/robot_localization-use-case-with-landmarks/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd have to see a sample odometry message, but just based on your description and launch file, my best guess is that you're having a transform issue. `ekf_localization_node` needs at least one message from one input source before it starts producing a state estimate. In your case, it will produce (a) an odometry message as `/odometry/filtered`, and (b) a transform from *map*->*odom*. Again, it will not produce either until it receives at least one message from one of its input sources. The problem is that your `/odom` message that you are using as input `odom0` probably has a `frame_id` of *odom*. In order to use that message, the filter first needs to transform it into the `world_frame` specified in the launch file, which in this case is *map*. Since `ekf_localization_node` **itself** is responsible for producing the *map*->*odom* transform, and it hasn't produced a state estimate yet, the transform doesn't exist. It's a chicken-or-egg problem. The easiest way to get around it is to start producing messages for your other input source, `/my_pose`.

EDIT: actually, after looking again at your `odom0` configuration, it appears that you're only fusing velocity, which should work. Can you post a sample `/odom` message?

EDIT 2 in response to comment: If you are using `amcl` to do global localization, then what do you gain from running `ekf_localization_node`? Regardless, you can't have two nodes publishing the same transform, so you'll have to stop one of them from publishing it. If `amcl` supports turning off the *map*->*odom* transform, then you can do that, and instead feed its output to `ekf_localization_node` as an additional input. I've not tried this before, but as long as the message type is correct, it may work.

Also, your `frame_ids` in the message you posted start with a forward slash, e.g., "/odom" and "/base_link." You should remove the forward slashes.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-08-19**:
Actually my bag was taken during an amcl localization, so the transform between odom and map exists also.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-08-20**:
Now it is working ! I tested it directly on the robot after I changed the odom publisher to set frame_id's without a slash. I think it was the problem. Thanks